# django can we select related a field on a prefetch related model?

Tags: django

Assuming these as django model for the sake of simplcity:

```
class A():

    a = manytomany('B')

class B():

    b = charfield()
    z = foreignkey('C')

class C():

    c = charfield()
```

Can we do something like this to fetch the `z` also:

```
foo = A.objects.get(pk = 1).prefetch_related('a').select_related('a__z')
```

Comment: This is all covered in the manual... https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/, but "yes" is the answer.

Comment: Actually, the answer is “no”, the `select_related` call as written in the question will not work. I'm going to add a new answer. By the way, the `get` call should be at the end, not before `select_related` and `prefetch_related`.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You only need one `prefetch_related` call:

```
foo = A.objects.prefetch_related('a__z').get(pk=1)
```

This will prefetch both tables. In Django 1.7+ you can improve performance by using a `Prefetch` object, as in [koniiiik's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26451891/113962).

Comment: i thought prefetch related only works on `manytomanyfield`, but it works on `foreignkey` too?

Comment: As Arnar says in the comments, this is covered by the [prefetch related docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related). Your use case is similar to the example `>>> Restaurant.objects.prefetch_related('best_pizza__toppings')`.

Comment: Are there any situations where this won't work? I'm having an issue where model a has a foreign key for b and a foreign key for c. I want to do c.objects.prefetch_related('a__b') but it only fetches the set for a and doesn't do anything for b.

Comment: @Adam It's not clear to me what your models are. You'd be better to ask a new question rather than trying to solve your problem in the comments here.

Comment: FarisNasution please consider accepting @koniiiik's answer, as it is better for Django 1.7+

Answer (score 60):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13973771/687488) is correct with versions of Django prior to 1.7. It produces three queries: first, fetch the instance of `A`, then fetch its related instances of `B` and finally fetch the instances of `C` related to those of `B` fetched in the second query.

Before Django 1.7, this is the best you can do, even though the second query could, in theory, select all `B` objects together with the related `C` objects joined through the `z` `ForeignKey`.

Starting with Django 1.7, there's a more advanced [`django.db.models.Prefetch`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) class which allows you to do just that. With `Prefetch` you can customize the queryset used to prefetch related objects like this:

```
foo = A.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('a', queryset=B.objects.select_related('z'))
).get(pk=1)
```

This results in only two queries (as opposed to three when using `prefetch_related('a__z')`) and lets the database take care of the second join, which should in theory result in slightly better performance.

Comment: This is awesome! I didn't know about Prefetch. Thanks. Note for anyone who uses it in the future: `Prefetch` is in the models import space, so to import it to use it as in the example: `from django.db.models import Prefetch`

Comment: Good point, I added the import path to the answer, as well as a link to the docs. Thanks for the suggestion.