# django loop through queryset and add a new property

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have two tables that I joined with a foreign key, I want to get all of the fields from one model and just one of the fields from the other model, how to I add on that field?

```
msos = Msos.objects.using('data').filter(id=121497).prefetch_related('mso_universe')
    for i in msos:
        for x in i.mso_universe.all():
            # I want to add x.population to each i
    data = serialize('json', data)
    return HttpResponse(data)
```

Comment: Does this help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13973422/django-can-we-select-related-a-field-on-a-prefetch-related-model

Comment: Can you post the relevant parts of your two models?

Comment: Also, not sure of your use case, but have you considered http://www.django-rest-framework.org which has excellent support for building serialized data exactly as you are trying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a solution, I think I worded my question wrong. I had to join the two tables, then I was able to use the below code to query what fields I wanted from both tables. Then I was able to have the data joined in a json file

```
    query = Mso.objects.using('data')
    values = query.values('mso__state','mso__name','mso__code','mso__county','mso__owner','population')
    results = values.filter(mso__owner=True)
    data = json.dumps(list(results), cls=DjangoJSONEncoder)
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='json')
```